# Java Hashmap where the Key is a File and the Value is a Model

Tags: java, hashmap, java-io

I'm working on a project where I have a hashmap with the key as a File object in Java IO library and a custom model object, called a DrawingModel as the value in the hashmap. When I change the model, I need to save the file. When I go through the following sequence of events:

1. I open a File
2. I do some changes
3. I save that file (File -> Save)
4. I Exit the file
5. I then Open that same file
6. However, it does not open!

My question is if I change the file (by saving) do I need to remove that key value pair from the Hashmap and add a new key value pair? Such that the value is the same but the keys are updated?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Sincerely,
nc5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you put the file Name as the Key instead of the File Object and handle the file editing/updating stuff through another logic. **A file object as key doesn't make much sense**.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Whilst I don't entirely understand (and thus condone) the application design, you should always use a `File` instance when referring to a file. Why bother to just use a `String` and remember it's really a file reference?

Comment: But the problems like closing/opening  streams as with this case  will keep happening and you will have to handle that using additional codes.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how your point is related to whether a `File` object is used to store the path to a file, rather than a `String`.

Comment: I think i didn't explain ma ans properly :) .. I totally agree that a file object should be always used to refer a file. But in this question, why it should be used as a key which points to another Object. ???  I just put forward  a suggestion to change the application design such that the map key be made the file name.

Comment: Hey Akhil, Thanks for your suggestion it turns out that using the file's canonical path was just what my hashmap needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The File object is little more than a wrapper to the path of the actual file. It does not lock your files in any way.

The locking is caused by some stream that is still open. I bet you are not closing your outputstream after saving into the file.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that might be the case but I wasn't 100% sure. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you think logically, your key is changed. And once it is changed, you would no more able to locate your data using that. You should insert a (new key, value) pair in your map.

Comment: The `File` instance doesn't change if the referenced file's content has changed.

Comment: Yes, specifically the `equals()` method is calculated only on the path that the `File` instance refers too.

Comment: What about `hashcode()`? I actually wanted to look at `hashcode()` method of `java.io.File`, but don't have source code handy. :(

Comment: From the JavaDocs: "*On UNIX systems, the hash code of an abstract pathname is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code of its pathname string and the decimal value 1234321. On Microsoft Windows systems, the hash code is equal to the exclusive or of the hash code of its pathname string converted to lower case and the decimal value 1234321. Locale is not taken into account on lowercasing the pathname string.*"

Answer (score 1):

**Always** `close()` the `file` that you **opened**, **else the file will not be updated.** And it will be also **better to close** the `Connection and Channel streams`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have closed the file stream (most upper one). I.e if you have opened several streams one over another, then make sure the top-most stream is closed. Otherwise the file will be locked by the operating system.